# Slicing cell cultures frozen in vitrified ice with a laser for CryoEM

Tags: cell-biology, microscopy

Could a cell culture frozen in vitrified ice for CryoEM be effectively sliced into thin planes and resolved images produced? I was thinking if this could be done to get images from inside a cell.

Comment: Maybe I should take this over to physics. But this is something I'm interested in and not sure were to start.